# How to show the hidden Navigation Drawer Hamburger icon?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have hidden the navigation drawer hamburger icon using the following code in onCreate.

```
 final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar!=null) {
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(null);
        }
```

When I move to other fragments also this is hidden, how can I bring the icon back once I move away from this fragment?

Comment: Best way to do that is to use a toolbar and insert toolbar in every fragment and then change it according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to get deafult hamburger_icon drawable

```
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

crate this **ic_drawer.xml** in drawable folder

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M3,18h18v-2L3,16v2zM3,13h18v-2L3,11v2zM3,6v2h18L21,6L3,6z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: I can't find "android.R.drawable.ic_drawer".

Comment: Thanks It worked., But one more question, which is the best place to keep this code? I want to get this invoked when ever user moves from the fragment.

Comment: I have hidden the icon from onCreate(), where should I place this code so that It will get displayed when the user leaves the fragment.

Comment: means you want to visible icon in some fragments right..?

Comment: For one particular fragment I want to hide it, in other fragments I should show it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153853/discussion-between-nilesh-rathod-and-sreekanth-karumanaghat).

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat try this `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(null);;
` to hide you icon from fragments

Answer (score 1):

You can set the icon using drawable

```
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.hamburger_icon);
```

Comment: But where is hamburger_icon drawable?